# Ordering of elements in C# enumeration with the same integer value

Tags: c#, .net

I have a simple enum:

```
enum E
{
    FullNameForA = 1,
    A = 1,
    FullNameForB = 2,
    B = 2
}
```

The goal is to be able to use different string values for the same integral values with a twist - FullNameFor* must be used as default. In other words, a user can provide E.A as an input but the code should use E.FullNameForA for output.

It seems like by default C# will use alphabetical ordering of elements with the same integral value, which makes my goal harder. Is that right? Any ideas how to overcome this?

Comment: Who are your users? Are they developers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It seems like by default C# will use alphabetical ordering of elements with the same integral value

In what context? When you convert the value back to a string? From the docs of [`Enum.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z):

> If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value and you attempt to retrieve the string representation of an enumeration member's name based on its underlying value, your code should not make any assumptions about which name the method will return.

(Note that the decision is in the BCL - it's not a *language* decision.)

I suggest that if you want a *canonical* string representation for each value, you create a `Dictionary<E, string>` and consult that rather than calling `ToString()`.

Comment: yes, ToString uses the very first element. Dictionary is probably the easiest here. I thought about using the longest one because only one of all values for the same int is really full and lengthy. But this will require numerous iteration over enum members which I don't particularly like. Having static dictionary eliminates this overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this alternative solution. You can decorate enum values with the DescriptionAttribute and to have a more human friendly name:

```
enum E
{
    [System.ComponentModel.Description("FullNameForA")]
    A = 1
}
```

Then you can extract the value of that attribute like so:

```
public static string AsString(this Enum value)
{
    var type = value.GetType();

    if (!type.IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException();

    var fieldInfo = type.GetField(value.ToString());
    if (fieldInfo == null) 
        return value.ToString();

    var attribs = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false) as DescriptionAttribute[];

    return attribs.Length > 0 ? attribs[0].Description : value.ToString();
}
```

This of course isn't the best performing solution because it relies on reflection.

Comment: Interesting idea. Basically integrated Dictionary suggested by Jon Skeet.